# Create nested list in jquery

Tags: jquery, list, nested

I have a div with this content

```
<h3>title list1</h3>
<ul><li>element1</li>
<li>element2</li>`</ul>
```

repeated many times

i want that clicking on the h3 the ul right after it is toggled using jquery. i've tried with:

```
.first()
```

But it toggles only the first ul not the first after the clicked h3, how can i do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `<ul>` elements always occur immediately after the `<h3>` elements, you can use [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/):

```
$("h3").click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggle();
});
```